# Is it possible to install pygame without internet connection?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I downloaded Pygame package from the internet and saved it to my flash drive to install it to another computer. The other computer had no internet connection, I thought internet connection isn't required if I had downloaded Pygame package. Is the internet connection required?.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible

1. open cmd
2. cd 'path to the package'
3. pip install pygame
4. enter

Comment: Just for clarification. my package is in .zip. after extracting, is it 'setup.py' I should refer to in the path?.